# Minimal amount of fetched bytes property not applied in spring-kafka

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

This is my consumer config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs(){
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "......MyEventDeserializer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "id");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG, "100000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG, "2000");

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, List<MyEvent>> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, List<MyEvent>>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, List<MyEvent>> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, List<MyEvent>> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }
}
```

What is important, I am setting the fetch.min.bytes and fetch.max.wait.ms config, and even though I can see these properties logged on startup:

```
21:50:53.412 [main] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.ConsumerConfig () - ConsumerConfig values: 
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = latest
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    enable.auto.commit = true
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 2000
    fetch.min.bytes = 100000
    group.id = id
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = null
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    ...
```

it does not affect the payload size that comes in every message to the consumer. When I log the size of the byteArray that comes into the deserializer it's constant (about 20kB - the amount of one message sent by the producer) and does not change despite applying the fetch.min.bytes property. Is there something I'm missing here that I should add for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a basic misunderstanding. What do you mean by "... for this to work"?

These properties have no impact on individual messages.

If your messages are exactly 20000 bytes, these settings mean a `poll()` will wait for 5 messages or 2 seconds, whichever comes first.

It's not a mechanism to "filter" out messages that are smaller than 10k, if that's what you are thinking.

With Spring for Apache Kafka, you can use a `FilteringMessageListenerAdapter` to filter out messages you are not interested in.

If you are using `@KafkaListener`, add a `RecordFilterStrategy` to the container factory and the adapter will be automatically applied.

Comment: `If your messages are exactly 20000 bytes, these settings mean a poll() will wait for 5 messages or 2 seconds, whichever comes first.` Excactly and this is not happening. The producer sends out many messages in a short period of time, but the consumer does not get the messages aggregated into groups of least 100000 bytes, it still gets every message one by one (and yes - I am sure that it takes less than 2 seconds to receive 100000 bytes).

Comment: But you said `the byteArray that comes into the deserializer it's constant`. Of course, they are still discrete records that have to be deserialized one-at-a-time. There is no aggregation at that level. It's simply the number of bytes to fetch on each poll, but each message is still separate. Those properties just influence how many records are fetched.